# Set exact option for select-box which generated on the fly with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, select

My AJAX function generates `#parent` select-box on the fly. The problem is, i can't set exact option after menu generation

Tried

```
window.onload = function () {
var parent='1';
$('#parent').val(parent);   
}
```

And

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var parent='1';
$('#parent').val(parent);   
});
```

no success!. Any suggetions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `onload` nor `ready` will wait for an Ajax request. Move the function to the callback that you pass to the success handler.

Answer (score 0):

Basiclly... You need to be sure that in `<option>` there is a value.
Here is example

(HTML - script.html)

```
<select id="parent">
    <option value="0">First</option>
    <option value="1">Second</option>
</select>
```

(JS - index.html)

```
$(function(){
    $.get('script.html', function(data){
        $('#someDiv').append(data); // appends your select list to some div

        /* after <select> is appended */
        var parent = '1';
        $('#parent').val(parent); // selects "Second" option
    })
})
```

Comment: loool. thx for fast reply mate, but we're talking about AJAX generated menus